# Excel search and replace only within a single cell

Tags: excel

Should be a pretty easy question to answer for someone who is use to excel.

If I have a cell containing a large IF/AND statement which references cells in column H and then I wish to use the same formula but replace all the H's with G's, is there a way to use the search and replace tool on a single cell so I am able to change all these H's to G's in one fell swoop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Replace window should have an advanced option to replace only within the selection. Should be pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I just had to click replace opposed to replace all.

Comment: Great. Please consider marking this as your answer. Thank you.